# Intention to treat principle in randomized crossover trials

Tags: crossover-study

Is it possible to use intention-to-treat principle in randomized studies with crossover design? Was it ever used in such studies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all the time.  In a crossover trial, the intention-to-treat principle says that participants should be analysed according to the treatment sequence they were assigned to at randomisation